# Differentiating the following function.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus-of-variations

An integral of the form : 
$$\int_a^b \sqrt{\frac {1+|y'(x)|^2}{2g(x-a)+v_a^2}}dx$$

The above integral is the Time taken for an object to fall under the action of gravity with some particular tragectory . 
I am trying to differentiate it wrt $y'$ in order to put the values in  Euler lagrange equation  and get the first variation.

I am confused with fact that $y'$ has a modulus . 
Can some one give me suggestions and help . 
Thanks 
P.S any other idea and explanations are very much welcome .

Comment: Differentiate it *wrt $y'$'*??

Comment: @Berci: Yes , wrt is with respect to y' . Or any other ideas are welcome to find the first variation.

Comment: Note that $|a|^2=a^2$ for all $a\in\mathbb R$.